# Set Eclipse to make 32 bit application

Tags: c, eclipse

I need to compile my C project that is developed on 64 bit Ubuntu Eclipse to 32bit one. I know that I must set -m32 switch for compiler. Is that enough? Where in Eclipse I can do that.

Comment: [Solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3488108/how-to-compile-for-32bit-with-eclipse)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Where in Eclipse I can do that*  It is general way i use to add flags to compiler in eclipse:
Right click on project => Properties => C/C++ Build => Settings => In Tool Settings tab choose GCC C++ Compiler or GCC C Compiler => Command (add your flag here)

[image]

Also you will have to link against 32 bit libraries.